# No such file or directorye

Tags: bash

I am trying to run [this bash script](https://github.com/facebookresearch/InferSent/blob/master/dataset/get_data.bash) which runs fine but gives error to the following lines.

```
cut -f2 $fpath | $preprocess_exec > SNLI/s1.$split
cut -f3 $fpath | $preprocess_exec > SNLI/s2.$split
```

and,

```
cut -f2 $fpath.tok | $preprocess_exec > MultiNLI/s1.$split
cut -f3 $fpath.tok | $preprocess_exec > MultiNLI/s2.$split
```

Error Message

```
: No such file or directorye
```

The problem is specifically in `$preprocess_exec` which is a [Sed script](https://github.com/facebookresearch/InferSent/blob/master/dataset/tokenizer.sed). The script says, it cannot find the file but I can see the input file is there where it should be.

Any idea why this is happening?

---

**Update**

I changed the command as follows and now there is no error produced by the bash script.

```
cut -f2 $fpath.tok | sed -f $preprocess_exec > MultiNLI/s1.$split
cut -f3 $fpath.tok | sed -f $preprocess_exec > MultiNLI/s2.$split
```

But I am doubting that `$preprocess_exec` is not making any changes to the input file.

Does anyone have any thought on this?

Comment: if you want to pass output of `cut` as file input to `sed`, then you'd need `xargs`.. something like `cut -f2 $fpath | xargs $preprocess_exec > SNLI/s1.$split` but that would not be robust at all... will break on filenames with space and so on

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... running your bash script in debug mode (-x) would help. Just guessing: is your sed script executable? If not...

```
chmod +x ./tokenizer.sed
```

Comment: ran it on debug mode but didn't get any help!